# Updating cloud function to suitable Node js version

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

The cloud function for the firebase FCM notification which was working fine with the earlier version of Node.js 8 but now as the node 8 is deprecated and needs to be updated, what changes should I make to the cloud function code, I have already installed Nodejs 14* on my machine

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only change you're absolutely required to make is not in your code at all.  Minimally, you should edit your package.json and make sure that the target node version is 10:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
```

Simply redeploy the function to use the node 10 runtime.

[Read more about migrating your functions to node 10](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/migrate-your-firebase-cloud-functions-to-node-js-10-d9c677933ee).

Comment: It says (on the console) that node 10 is Beta. Is there any way to migrate to a version, which is not deprecated and not Beta? I tried using "engines": {"node": "8.12.1"}. However, I got a message (while deploying) that only 8 and 10 are valid values for this property. Thanks...

Comment: That might be a mistake/oversight in the console, because Cloud Functions is fully released from the perspective of Google Cloud Platform.  I would contact Firebase support and ask them if that beta message is correct.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the blog post but it's behind a paywall. Can I access the resource some where else?

Comment: @flutter You can use a private/incognito window.

Comment: I'd be careful with that, changing your Node version might break some of your functions. Most of the environment variables are not being set automatically with Node 10 anymore. Some useful links:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/migrating/nodejs-runtimes

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#environment_variables_set_automatically